# SVN pre-commit hook from Synology NAS

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, synology

I'm having a problem with a pre-commit hook that I'm trying to get working for my users.  I have SVN running from a Synology NAS.  I'm trying to get the pre-commit hook to force users to comment on their committed changes and reject commits that have a lack of comments.  Here is the code that I have in the hook so far.

```
REPOS="$1"
TXN="$2"
# Make sure that the log message contains some text.
# Example SVNLOOK - SVNLOOK=/var/packages/SVN/target/bin/svnlook
#svnlook=/var/packages/svn/target/repo/test_svn/
SPATH=/var/packages/svn/target/repo/svn_test/
$SVNLOOK log -t "$TXN" "$REPOS" | grep "[a-zA-Z0-9]" > /dev/null || exit 1
```

The specific problem that I'm having is that there is an error that is thrown on "log" on the last line.  The error states that the command "log" cannot be found.  Everything else seems to check out ok as far as I can tell.

Comment: What happens if you uncomment the line that starts with `#svnlook`? Looks to me like you don't have `$SVNLOOK` defined, so it's trying to run `log` as the executable instead of the `svnlook` subcommand.

Comment: Alroc, If I do that, the same error message is thrown stating that "log: command not found".

Comment: Is bash case-sensitive WRT variable names? You have lower case in that line but upper case when you use it.

Comment: Interesting.  I changed 

    '#svnlook=/var/packages/svn/target/repo/test_svn/'

to look like 

    #SVNLOOK=/var/packages/svn/target/repo/test_svn/

It then threw an error stating that no such file or directory exists.  I then changed it to look like this

    #SVNLOOK=/var/packages/SVN/target/repo/test_svn/

It now errors out stating that the directory DOES exist.  

I'm confused, doesn't it actually WANT to see that directory or am I missing something?

Comment: Does anyone else have any further suggestions?  It feels like I'm almost there on making this work, but can't seem to figure out what I'm missing.

Comment: Ok, so I've changed my line to `SVNLOOK=/usr/bin/svnlook` and now it throws the error of "E000002 Can't open file '/var/packages/SVN/target/repo/svn_test/format': No such file or directory.  The funny thing is, when I SSH into the Synology and go to that directory, it does actually exist.  What am I missing?

Comment: Your `SVNLOOK` environment variable should be pointing to the `svnlook` executable (program), not a directory.

Comment: @alroc : Yeah, I stumbled upon that this morning just before you posted.  Just ran into another error though as per my last posting before yours.